# SQL - Function to divide value among rows

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I normally don't do database programming so Im rusty on how to do certain stuff.  But I have an issue where I'm to take an item and if this item is in the same location but in different placements, divide the value of said item among the sum count between placements.

here is my table structure:

```
LOCATION   PLACEMENT   VALUE  COUNT   ITEM
25         12345        100    10      55555  <----
25         67890        100    20      55555  <----
25         11111        50      5      00000
25         22222        75      5      11111
```

In other words `Item (55555)` is in 2 placements and the value of this item is `100`

The new value should be: `PLACEMENT 12345` will be (10/30) *100 = 33.3 and `PLACEMENT 67890` will be (20/30) * 100 = 66.7

Any idea how to do this in SQL or HQL?

Comment: Its actually 20 for the 2nd row...sorry for the mistake, but I no I need to divide 100 based off the total count between the rows that have the same item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table new as
select  item,count(distinct placement) as dist_placement,count(count)as count,sum(count) as s_count
from mytable
group by item,location;

hive> select * from new;
OK
00000   1   1   5
11111   1   1   5
55555   2   2   30



Create table final as
select b.location as location,b.placement as placement, CASE
WHEN a.count=2 and a.dist_placement=2 then cast(((b.count/a.s_count)*b.value) as double) 
ELSE cast(b.value as double)
END , b.count as count, b.item as item
from new a 
join mytable b
on a.item=b.item;

select * from final;
```

output

```
location placement value               count    item 
   25     12345    33.33333333333333    10      55555  
   25     67890    66.66666666666666    20      55555  
   25     11111    50.0                 5       00000
   25     22222    75.0                 5       11111
```

if you give input with same placement and different item

```
LOCATION   PLACEMENT   VALUE  COUNT   ITEM
25         12345        100    10      55555  <----
25         12345        100    20      55555  <----
25         11111        50      5      00000
25         22222        75      5      11111
```

output will be

```
LOCATION   PLACEMENT   VALUE  COUNT   ITEM
   25      12345       100.0    10   55555  
   25      12345       100.0    20   55555  
   25      11111        50.0    5    00000
   25      22222        75.0    5    11111
```

May I right, let me know if you have other requirements.

Comment: Adding this initially worked great.  Had to tweak a little.  I noticed you did where `count and placement = 2`.  I should have said where there is 2 or more.

Comment: Is there a way to SUM the value column?  when I try to put a sum function around the calculation I get "Not Yet supported place for UDAF 'SUM'"

Comment: When your count and placement > 2 in this condition you only have to change, WHEN a.count>1 and a.dist_placement>1 in query, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more efficient way to do it, but in two steps you can add up the item_count and then create the new value by dividing it through.

```
create table new as select
item, sum(count) as item_count
from old
group by item, location, placement;

create table new2 as select
a.*,
b.item_count,
a.count/b.item_count as new_count
from old a
left join new b
on a.item=b.item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM
(
       SELECT 25 LOCATION,12345 PLACEMENT,100 VALUE  ,10 [COUNT], 55555 ITEM 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 25 ,        67890 ,       100 ,   20,55555  
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 25 ,        11111 ,       50  ,    5,00000
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 25 ,        22222 ,       75  ,    5, 11111
)TAB
```

Your result is below

```
SELECT *,
CAST(([COUNT]/CAST(SUM([COUNT]) OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM)AS NUMERIC(20,2)))*VALUE AS NUMERIC(20,1)) Result 
FROM #TEMP
```

[image]